# how to test for validation error when a parameter has a grailsparametermap property?

Tags: unit-testing, grails, integration-testing, grails-2.0, grails-domain-class

I am using grails and i want to assert if a field has an error. This works well for firstName, lastName but is not working for address. Basically, the following parameter causes a validation error on address because for area "MARIOLAND" isn't acceptable. The assertion should pass but it fails. Maybe i am not extracting address in a correct way. I appreciate any help! Thank you!

```
controller.params.putAll(

            firstName : "asd",
            lastName : "asd",
            email : "asd@gmail.com",
            password : "asd",
            address :  new GrailsParameterMap([country: 'usa', address1: "24 Willey Mayes Plaza", city: "San Francisco", area: "MARIOLAND", postalCode: "94107"], controller.params.getRequest())


            )



        def model = controller.create()
        def user = model.userInstance
        user.validate()


        assertTrue user.errors.hasFieldErrors("address")
        //the above assertion should pass since MARIOLAND on area of address causes validation error, but it fails
```

Comment: Have you used `mockForContraintsTest`http://grails.org/doc/latest/api/grails/test/GrailsUnitTestCase.html#mockForConstraintsTests(java.lang.Class, java.util.List) to test the constrainsts? Can you add the actual test and the domain class to complete the question?

Answer (score 0):

I think this is related to below two issues which are still open.

[**GRAILS-10284**](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-10284) and [**GRAILS-11268**](https://jira.grails.org/browse/GRAILS-11268)

`deepValidate` does not work on associations or on associated fields. Here is how I am expecting your tests would be:

```
import grails.test.mixin.TestFor
import spock.lang.Specification
import grails.test.mixin.TestMixin
import grails.test.mixin.support.GrailsUnitTestMixin
import org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet.mvc.GrailsParameterMap

@TestFor(UserController)
@TestMixin(GrailsUnitTestMixin)
@Mock([User, Address])
class UserControllerSpec extends Specification {

    void setup(){
        mockForConstraintsTests User
    }

    void "test something"() {
        given:
        controller.params.putAll(
            firstName : "asd",
            lastName : "asd",
            email : "asd@gmail.com",
            password : "asd",
            address :  new GrailsParameterMap([country: 'usa', 
                           address1: "24 Willey Mayes Plaza", 
                           city: "San Francisco", 
                           area: "MARIOLAND", 
                           postalCode: "94107"], controller.request)
        )

        // Also fails if we set address to params
        /*controller.params.address = [
              country: 'usa', address1: "24 Willey Mayes Plaza", 
              city: "San Francisco", area: "MARIOLAND", postalCode: "94107"
        ]*/

        when:
        def model = controller.index()
        def user = model.userInstance

        then:
        !user.validate() // FAILS
        user.errors.hasFieldErrors("address")
    }

    void "test address"() {
        given:
        controller.params.putAll(
            new GrailsParameterMap([country: 'usa', 
                address1: "24 Willey Mayes Plaza", city: "San Francisco", 
                area: "MARIOLAND", postalCode: "94107"], 
             controller.params.request) )

        when:
        def model = controller.address()
        def address = model.addressInstance
        mockForConstraintsTests Address

        then:
        !address.validate() // PASSES
        address.errors.hasFieldErrors("area")
    }
}

class User {
    String firstName, lastName, email, password
    Address address

    static constraints = {
        // Tests will pass if address validated explicitly
        //address validator: { it.validate() }
    }
}

class Address {
    String country, address1, city, area, postalCode

    static constraints = {
        area notEqual: "MARIOLAND"
    }
}

class UserController {
    def index() { 
        def user = new User(params)
        [userInstance: user]
    }

    def address(){
        def address = new Address(params)
        [addressInstance: address]
    }
}
```

Comment: sorry but i am just looking for a way to assert the statement like the way i am doing. i.e i just want to pick the address field and check if it has error. There should be a way.

Comment: Yes there is a way. Try `user.address.validate()` and `user.address.errors.hasFieldErrors("area")`. @user3256520

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I get the error :  java.lang.NullPointerException: Cannot invoke method validate() on null object on this line user.address.validate()

Comment: Which version of Grails? Can you address the comment to your question as well?

Comment: i am using 2.2.0 http://grails.org/doc/2.2.0/guide/gettingStarted.html. Sorry what do you mean by comment to my question?